# Should we add "software development tools" to the don't ask section of the FAQ?

Tags: discussion, site-topic, faq-proposed

This meta question is inspired by the following question:  [VCS + IssueTracking + CI for free?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/vcs-issuetracking-ci-for-free)

It has a close vote, but I wanted to get some more community input on whether or not developer tools, software architecture, and IT Architecture questions should be added to the "don't ask" section of the FAQ, as guidance for our moderators and community members.

**UPDATE:** Not sure "software architecture" is the right word to use to describe continuous integration and version control. I put "software development tools" in the title originally. Yegor's response was possibly based on me using the right term to describe the question.

Answer (score 1):

"Software architecture" questions definitely don't belong to our site. But this question is not about architecture, but about choosing the right tools/instruments to do the project management. I think it's relevant to us.

In general, I think that every question that **should be answered by a project manager** is a good fit for us.

Comment: Okay, I can see the argument that this could be relevant to PM's, but this seems like a not constructive question that is really only generating spam answers or just a list of things with no explanation as to which is best. I was thinking of closing it, but I was hoping to get some more community support first. We're doing a better job of having more community involvement in these sorts of decisions, which is important in the march towards good quality, growth and graduation.

Comment: Actually, the only part of that that could be related to PM is the issue tracker portion, but the other two parts aren't. Not saying that means we should close it on that basis, just wanted to clarify my stance on the on-topic issue. Still, I think it may eventually need to be closed as not constructive or at the very least "protected" so 1 rep users don't keep bumping it back to the top with their spam. :)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to follow up and answer my own question, since this is a bit of a complex question. There are two issues at hand:  Is it on topic?  and is it constructive.

From former discussions [Why did no one vote to close this question about working on a codebase remotely?](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/why-did-no-one-vote-to-close-this-question-about-working-on-a-codebase-remotely) we know that questions that aren't about project management aren't on topic. However, as Yegor points out, this one isn't architecture. Also, I agree that at least part of it is related to PM, while part of it is software development.

However, from [We Will Be Closing All Tool Recommendations within 2 Weeks](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351/we-will-be-closing-all-tool-recommendations-within-2-weeks) and [Cleaning up Tags](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/397/cleaning-up-tags), as well as [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), we know that questions asking for links to tools aren't very constructive questions, as they:

- Don't make it clear what the best answer is.
- Tend to attract a lot of spam or answers that don't explain why it's the best solution.
- Don't involve sharing any expertise, something that we've determined is important is that [questions and answers involve learning through induction or deduction](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/a/361/34).

As a result of those discussions, community consensus appears to be that we're happy to see list questions disappear and agree with the SE policies. Mark even created a tag to further help highlight the fact that questions involving tools should be more about how to use them, not just listing or recommending them.

I went ahead and closed it as not constructive, and I won't make any FAQ changes at this time.